# USB - UART Windows COM Port

Tags: usb

I have playing with one of my usb devices in my windows laptop and to my surprise I am able to change the baudrate, parity, and other parameters in the device manager window.

To my knowledge, UART and USB are both serial protocols but the PHY layer is different as well as the encoding.

How does my computer allow to change the baudrate, if I am using a USB? Does it have my computer a UART to USB converter for each of the USB ports?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It is a power supply that can be controlled remotely.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the BAUD rate of the serial signals put out by the device, not the actual USB communications speed.

USB speed and the UART serial signal speed are two entirely different things, they are not related at all.

Think about it as the actual device being a small black box (the UART) that takes USB signals in one side, and puts out slower serial signals on the other side.

The USB side will operate at the USB speeds of 12Mbps (USB1) or 480Mbps (USB2), while the other side is generally far slower and in the 120kbps range. In between those two sides is some buffer and electronics to say "hold up, wait for me to send this" to the USB side and to pass on data when received.

Comment: So it seems to me that the UART signal is tunneled in the USB protocol. Does the USB hub in the laptop need extra hardware to emulate the UART? Or is just done in the software layer? I have seen someone calling Virtual Port COM, is tha correct? Could anyone point out a good reading resource about it?

Comment: Essentially it is done in software at both ends of a USB link. The driver says to Windows "I'm a COM port, show me to people!" and people then poke serial data at it. The underlying driver packages up the data, points it at the device at the end of the cable and sends it on. The device then unpacks the USB packet, decodes the data you told it to send, and then wiggles the serial data lines as appropriate. The reverse happens to go in the other direction. It is a "Virtual" COM port because there is an extra layer of abstraction from a "real" port when you use USB.